# Replace X or Y with J or Q using expressions

Tags: .net, regex

I am wondering if this is possible in one operation rather than two?

1.

I have this expression to find a brace which is not preceded with a space:

```
(?<!\s)\)
```

I replace it with  `)`

2.

I can then do similar for the opening brace:

```
\((?!\s)
```

This I replace with `(`

Can I somehow do a single find expression using OR :

```
((?<!\s)\)|\((?!\s))
```

And with a single replace expression somehow do 1 and 2 at the same time?

Comment: @Thefourthbird ... not quite -  I find the parenthesis and replace it with a space and the same parenthesis.

Comment: I see, that space does not show in the question. I upvoted the question though. I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lookarounds, both  lookbehind and lookahead, and just replace with a space

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\s)(?=\))|(?<=\()(?!\s)", " ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9S0w3D/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<!\s)(?=\))` - a location that is not immediately preceded with a whitespace and is immediately followed with  `)`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\()(?!\s)` - a location that is immediately preceded with a `(` char and is not immediately followed with a  whitespace.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qWuPr9):

```
var input = @"(foobar)  (fo) (ob (ar";
Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\s)(?=\))|(?<=\()(?!\s)", " ") );
# => ( foobar )  ( fo ) ( ob ( ar
```

Comment: Upped. Very nice Wiktor.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `(?<!\s)(\))|(\()(?!\s)` with `$2 $1` substitution.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X911TU/1/)

**Details**

`(?<!\s)(\))`: match brace `)` which is not preceded by space as first group (`$1`)

`|`: or

`(\()(?!\s)`: match brace `(` which is not followed by space as second group (`$2`)

replace with `$2 $1`: one of the matching groups will be empty, so it can create your result and add space in proper place

.NET code sample:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
        string input = "(foobar)  (fo) (ob (ar";

        // Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\s)(\))|(\()(?!\s)", "$2 $1");

        // Write the output.
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

output:

```
(foobar)  (fo) (ob (ar
( foobar )  ( fo ) ( ob ( ar
```

Comment: Upped. Thank you for explanation.